# SatelliteMenu liner display, make icon separate

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I try to use git Hub lib [link](https://github.com/siyamed/android-satellite-menu), but I get NullPointerException. This page is a Fragment, which use V4 lib. This initialize under onCreateView.

```
mActivity = getActivity();
SatelliteMenu menu=(SatelliteMenu)mActivity.findViewById(R.id.satelliteMenu);

List<SatelliteMenuItem> items = new ArrayList<SatelliteMenuItem>();
items.add(new SatelliteMenuItem(4, R.drawable.ic_1));
items.add(new SatelliteMenuItem(4, R.drawable.ic_3));
menu.addItems(items);  // get null pointer here.
```

I can not get the SatelliteMenu project, any one can help me thx?

The first problem I fixed.
final View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.orders, container, false);

But I want SatellliteMenu Liner display, make the SpacingDegree(0), but all the icon at one point, so How I wan separate them in one line.

Comment: show us your complete fragment and activity code

Comment: Already fix the first problem, I want the SatelliteMenu in one line not cycle, how to do that ? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SatelliteMenu menu = (SatelliteMenu)root.findViewById(R.id.satelliteMenu);
 Fix the problem~~

Answer (score 1):

`findViewById` returns null when it doesn't find the view in the view hierarchy. Make sure you have a `SatelliteMenu` in the appropriate layout file and that it has `android:id=@+id/satelliteMenu`

Comment: But I want SatellliteMenu Liner display, make the SpacingDegree(0), but all the icon at one point, so How I wan separate them in one line.

Comment: The problem you posted about was a NullPointerException on the line `menu.addItems(items);`. I don't see how anything in your last comment is relevant to that problem. The activity needs to have a view with the appropriate ID in it's current layout at the time you call `findViewById`, otherwise `null` is returned, which would result in a `NullPointerException` at the line you specified. If you have a different problem, then open a new question.